# CKEditor is adding inline style to resize my textarea on node add/edit form

Tags: entities, wysiwyg, input-formats

No matter how many rows I define the textarea to be in the content type configuration, I get a huge editor taking up almost the whole browser window in the node add/edit page. I tracked this down to CKEditor, which is hiding the actual textarea and adding an inline height to the table cell it uses to display the iframe containing the actual field. (Argh.)

Please share any advice on how to make it stop or override it? Since it's inline, I'm not hopeful about using normal CSS.

[image: screenshot of code from node/add page]

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this is a documented problem in CKEditor. There are some workarounds posted at https://www.drupal.org/node/1154730 but I'd also be intersted in hearing any other ideas.